# Concatenating an argument with a predefined token

Tags: c++, arguments, concatenation, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am defining a macro in which I take a token as the argument, and append it to a prefix, like this:

```
Enum::Type var = FULL_NAME(enum1);
```

Which should translate to:

```
Enum::Type var = Enum::Type::enum1;
```

I read you can use the ## operator to concatenate two arguments, like this:

```
#define glue(a, b) (a ## b)
```

But can I use it like

```
#define FULL_NAME(name) (Enum::Type ## name)
```

?

If not, what's the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

No, `##` is for creating *tokens*. You don't need that, and it won't work.

What you want is much simpler:

```
#define FULL_NAME(name) (Enum::Type::name)
```

Although you might think of `Enum::Type::enum1` as a single name, it is actually five tokens. You could write it with whitespace or even comments between the tokens, although I wouldn't recommend that other than as a learning exercise:

```
 Enum   ::/* the outer namespace */
    Type  // the inner namespace
        :: enum1
```